# How do you clean a petrol smell off rubber?

Tags: cleaning

Not sure if this is the right forum for this question, but I suspect the readers here will probably know.

I have a short length of rubber coated pipe used to provide some ventilation for a small enclosure. Unfortunately, it smells of petrol or perhaps some other hydrocarbon solvent. I can't replace it, unfortunately, as it's glued in place (nor can I get the installer back). But I can and have washed it with soap and water. This hasn't done much if anything to reduce the smell. What else can I try?

Comment: are you able to coat it? If so let me know and I'll post a formal answer.

Comment: Possibly. It would need a very small brush with a long handle, though.

Comment: Having you tried soaking the pipe in hot water with washing powder, for few hours? And while replying if you don't put the name of the person starting with @, the person won't be notified.